# Swift (Parse) new row from the top TableViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I can not add a new row to the top of the tableViewCell. 
I create a function and place it in the viewDidload and refresh.Removed function  Reload data.
my Code:

Refresh:

```
@objc func refreshing() {

        insertNewRow()
        loadObjects1()
        loadObjects2()
        loadObjects3()


        tableView.reloadData()

        refresh.endRefreshing()

    }
```

Parse :

```
func loadObjects1() {
        let query = Soccer.query() as! PFQuery<Soccer>

        query.findObjectsInBackground  { (objects, error) in
            if error == nil {
                self.soccerString.removeAll()

                self.soccerString = objects!

                self.tableView.reloadData()
            } else {
                print(error!)
            }

            }
    }
```

add new row Top:

```
func insertNewRow() {
        soccerString.append(Soccer())
        tableView.beginUpdates()
        soccerString.insert(Soccer(), at: 0)
        tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:0, section:0)], with: .automatic)
        tableView.endUpdates()
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`insertNewRow` doesn't work because you are adding **two** new items, one at the top (`insert(...`) and one at the bottom (`append(...`) but inserting only **one** row in the table view.

This is sufficient

```
func insertNewRow() {
    soccerString.insert(Soccer(), at: 0)
    tableView.insertRows(at: [IndexPath(row:0, section:0)], with: .automatic)
}
```

Comment: Prompt and this function is necessary only in ViewDidLoad add?if I have refresh, this function should also be placed here?

Comment: this must be indicated beginUpdates and endUpdates?

Comment: No, this must **not** *be indicated beginUpdates and endUpdates* since it's only a single insert operation. I don't understand your workflow anyway. In `insertNewRow` you are inserting a new row but in `loadObjects1()` you are removing all objects from `soccerString` which practically removes also the new inserted object. And it seems that you are calling `reloadData()` unnecessarily too many times.

Comment: Got it, right now I'll clean the code and I'll try. Thanks for the help